# 表からシート名を参照し、各シート内の特定セルの値を求めたい

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

GAS初心者です。
同じスプレッドシート内にたくさんのシートがあることを前提にし、
"シート16"というシートに取り出したいシート名が格納しています。
そこから、各シートの特定なセルから値を取得したいです。
下のように書きましたが、
`m = psheet.getRange(10,3).getValue();`
行にエラーが発生し、getValue()ができなくなりました。

どなたか、アドバイス頂ければ幸いです。

---

```
function hiyo(){
  var usheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('シート16');
  var psheet, m=0;

  for(x=1;x!=5;x++){
    t = usheet.getRange(x,1).getValue();
    psheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("'"+t+"'");
    m = psheet.getRange(10,3).getValue();
  }

  return m;
}
```

---

Comment: エラーメッセージも追加してください

Comment: 「psheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("'"+t+"'");」の("'"+t+"'")　を　(t)　に変更してみてください。getSheetByNameの引数は文字列で、t にはシート名を表す文字列が入っているはずですから。